# Callback was already called error

Tags: truffle, metamask, ethereumjs

I am following this tutorial to create betting app that will do transactions on basis of the results of a winner

Link to Tutorial: https://medium.com/coinmonks/tutorial-create-a-sports-betting-dapp-on-the-ethereum-blockchain-part-2-cd4753afe702

When I try to run migration i get the following error
[image]

This is my truffle.js file

[image]

I have tried duplicate solutions but nothing is working for me

My versions

**Truffle** *v5.0.2* (core: 5.0.2)

**Solidity** *v0.5.0* (solc-js)

**Node** *v14.15.1*

Comment: Could you provide your node and truffle versions please ?

Comment: sure
Truffle v5.0.2 (core: 5.0.2)
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v14.15.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a truffle version that is not compatible with your node version.

Starting at [5.1.49](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases/tag/v5.1.49) truffle supports node 14, prior versions such as yours may lead to very [similar issues](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/3008).

Upgrade truffle with this command (assuming a global install of truffle) :

```
npm update -g truffle
```

Comment: It solved my error